# Autobiography of Roger Scruton?

Tags: reference-request, aesthetics

The current Wikipedia article on English philosopher [Roger Scruton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Scruton) (who specializes in [aesthetics](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1730/philosophy-question-challenge-aesthetics)) makes reference to an autobiography without citing further details:

> In May 1968, the French student rebellion marked Scruton enough to
>   afford a chapter in his autobiography.

Is there among his many books one that qualifies as his autobiography or is this an error of fact?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is merely a reference question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See :

- Roger Scruton, [Gentle Regrets : Thoughts from a Life](http://books.google.it/books/about/Gentle_Regrets.html?id=-h3XAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) (2005) :

> > These autobiographical essays are the nearest Roger Scruton has ever got to writing a full autobiography.